# String.replace not working

Tags: java, string

I am trying to replace the "X" in this String with another char by sending it to a method...

This is the String I'm sending:

```
adress = "http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/X/changes.html";
//Caliing method
getadress(adress,i)
```

and this is the method:

```
private static String getadress(String stadress, Integer i) {
    stadress.replaceAll("X",i.toString());
    System.out.print(stadress);
    return stadress;
}
```

The method doesn't work for me and I guess it's because I'm not using it correctly.

What I was trying to do:

```
adress.replace("X","2"); //for example ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it right. You just need to update the `stadress` variable with the new value:

```
private static String getadress(String stadress, Integer i) {
   stadress = stadress.replaceAll("X",i.toString());//assign with new value here
   System.out.print(stadress);
   return stadress;
}
```

Or, as a shorter way of achieving this:

```
private static String getadress(String stadress, Integer i) {
   return stadress.replaceAll("X",i.toString());//assign with new value here on one line
   //System.out.print(stadress);
   //return stadress;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Methods that operate on `String`s return the changed result; they do not modify the original `String`.  Change

```
stadress.replaceAll("X",i.toString());
```

to

```
stadress = stadress.replaceAll("X",i.toString());
```